# Are there any real life mobile apps built in MAUI Blazor?

Tags: mobile, blazor, maui, hybrid-mobile-app

If not, how can we know if MAUI Blazor is suitable for mobile development? I'm talking specifically about MAUI hybrid mobile apps with a Blazor webview. Are there any companies currently implementing it?

Googled it and looked on Microsoft's webpage for more info, but MAUI Mobile seems to be just a concept

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Googled it and looked on Microsoft's webpage for more info, but MAUI Mobile seems to be just a concept

You mean you didn't find any official documentation about MAUI Mobile for Blazor?

You can refer to this doc: [Build a .NET MAUI Blazor app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/maui?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=windows). Things about Blazor is in ASP.NET Core documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly companies that are using it (mine is actually thinking about using it soon) but none that I know / could find that are publicly stating it.

In it's actual state maui still have a lot of problems that make it a not so good choice for companies (memory leaks, design issues, ...) even more then you have really solid and mature technologies existing on the market (flutter for example).

Keep in mind that .NET maui is still young and that it's still under developpement (.NET 8 version is trying to fix most of the current issue). I also think that as long as microsoft (or some other major company) doesn't use maui for a concrete project it will never really take off, since there will be no one to push it forward and ensure that the framework can efficiently be used in a real environement. Flutter is a good exemple of that with the mobile app "Google Ads" developped by google itself.

I still think it's really promising and that most of the work is done, I have good hope that in 1 or 2 years it will be a totally viable option (as long as Microsoft doesn't decide to throw it out).

Answer (score 0):

There is a customer showcase by Microsoft. It introduces some companies that uses .NET MAUI:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/customers/maui

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587